# Passing parameters to dialog flow via fulfillment text

Tags: dialogflow-es

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var body="";
exports.weatherWebhook = (req, res) => {
    const host = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/';
    const wwoApiKey = '7ffbb59524a81a6ac42ac3e942f68c5d';
    var city = req.body.queryResult.parameters['geo-city'];
    callWeatherApi(city).then((output) => {
        //console.log(output);
            res.json({ 'fulfillmentText': output }); // Return the results of the weather API to Dialogflow
     }).catch(() => {
        //console.log('ERROR');
            res.json({ 'fulfillmentText':'hello'});
    });
}
    function callWeatherApi (city) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var path = 'data/2.5/weather?' +'APPID=' + wwoApiKey +
        '&q=' + encodeURIComponent(city)+'&units=imperial';
         request(host+path,function(error,res,body)
        {   
            /*var response = JSON.parse(body);
                var forecast = response['main']['temp'];
                var output='Current temperature is '+forecast;
                resolve(output);*/
            }).on('data', (d) => { body += d; console.log(body); })
        .on('end', () => {
            var response = JSON.parse(body);
                var forecast = response['main']['temp'];
                var output='Current temperature is ${forecast}';
                resolve('abc')})
        .on('error', (error) => {
                console.log(`Error calling the weather API: ${error}`)
                reject();
            });


  });
}
```

The output is not getting passed into webhook ,only hello is getting printed on the dialogflow console.When i remove the exports.webhook function and just hard code the city,output is getting printed on the terminal.why tis happens?

Comment: if fulfillment text is set to `hello` then you have problem in sending request to API

Comment: Which errors are logged on console when you call it?

Comment: errors:could not handle the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you query responds fine.
"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?APPID=7ffbb59524a81a6ac42ac3e942f68c5d&q=houston&units=imperial"

so i'd check to see if your agent is sending the 'geo-city' parameters. you can see it in the dialogflow console bottom right when you say the city.
or console.log(city) to see if the params get passed. if not fix your dialogflow agent.

if it is sending the params, then check your what is in res or body after this line:
request(host+path,function(error,res,body)

Comment: params works fine.couldn't check the res and body..unable to print in console too